# DataGridView size changes automatically according to the form's size

Tags: c#

I have a dataGridView in a form I want it's position to be 1 inch from left, top, right and I want it's height to be 60% of the form. I used anchor to all direction but then the space left under the grid id absoulot and not proportional. I do not want to use Dock to top because I want some space between the top and the grid
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy once you set the anchor and dock properties.
if you want the grid to be proportional to the form insert it to a panel table and set the dock property to the table and the table docks to the form